# Executing code after all skin parts have been added

Tags: apache-flex

I have several skin parts defined in a custom component and I want to execute some code after **all** parts have been added.

Currently, my only idea is to use if statement in overrided partAdded method to test if all parts have been added. Something like this:

```
override protected function partAdded(partName:String, instance:Object):void
{
    super.partAdded(partName, instance);

    if (part1 && part2 && part3 && part4) {
                 some code...
    }
}
```

But, I wonder is there some more elegant solution, some specific method that I could override, or event that I could use for this?

Thanks,

Comment: I'm curious, what sort of code do you need to execute that is dependent upon the existence of skin parts?  Seems like there could be an easier way to do this.

Comment: Component is a square grid with 9 equal fields. Each field is a skin part of a main component. After all parts have been added code needs to do some numerical calculations and set properties of each part.

Comment: Without knowing much more, it sounds like this might be better handled in the component rather than forcing the skin to be so intimate with the data.

Comment: Well, this seemed for me like the most logical solution. Here are the details.
Main custom component represents a trigram grid like this: http://www.alphegalivingconcepts.com/img/Icd_Trigrams.jpg. It has some properties that are used for calculation and are not displayed.

Every grid field is represented with another custom component having those symbols and names in the picture as its properties (Label skin parts).

Now, the Main custom component has 9 of grid field components as it's skin parts. I've put that because they are part of visual representation of the Main component. Thoughts?

Comment: @Wade There are a number of reasons why one would want to execute code only once all skin parts have been added to the component. Skin parts are usually added to a component because this component needs to access them at some point. One reason could be for example that you don't want to pollute your code with null checks. By the way, Tom Lee solution is a proper way to deal with this.

Answer (score 1):

Override attachSkin, and place your code after the call to `super.attachSkin().`